# Strange error when running update-grub

Tags: grub2

The errors appear when updating grub, either manually or when running apt upgrade. Here is the output:

```
{
Generating grub configuration file ...
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
  Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
done
}
```

I've been seeing this message for months and months but everything seems to work fine. This is Ubuntu Server 16.04.01 which was upgraded from 14.04, although the errors were appearing before that time.

I've checked `/etc/default/grub` but don't see anything wrong. Would love to know the cause of this...

edit: contents of /etc/default/grub

```
    # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Likely to be related with some problem with kernel 4.4.0-34 which may have been improperly removed.

Comment: that's very likely. I had a nightmare with kernels last year trying to get a usb tv stick to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after clearing out old kernels and looking at grub config files I went back to google and found a link which mentioned, in passing, a similar error - http://www.hpuxtips.es/?q=content/red-hat-openstack-administration-cl210-exam-notes

```
Configuration setting "snapshot_autoextend_percent" invalid. It's not part of any section.
```

This pointed me to vlm.

I found that running lvm commands, such as pvdisplay gave the same error (although the command did actually work):

```
Configuration setting "types" invalid. It's not part of any section.
```

So I had a look at my etc/lvm/lvm.conf file and the only line with "types" in it was:

```
types = [ "bcache", 16 ]
```

I have commented this out and I can now run update-grub and pvdisplay without any errors.

If anyone is able to shed light on what this setting does and if I need it then please let me know. Certainly everything seems to work perfectly still.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever manually edit your `grub.cfg` file?

Anyways, you might want to backup your current `grub.cfg` file by typing the following command in terminal:

```
sudo mv /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg.bak
```

and then generate a new one by typing:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If anything goes wrong (it shouldn't though) you can restore your previous `grub.cfg` file and then update grub again by typing:

```
sudo mv /boot/grub/grub.cfg.bak /boot/grub/grub.cfg && sudo update-grub
```

Comment: If the 4.4.0-34 kernel wasn't properly uninstalled - as the error suggests -  the results will be exactly the same.

Comment: @CelticWarrior - The message did not say anything about a Kernel uninstallation.

Comment: I've tried the above command to regenerate grub.cfg but no dice. For the record i've never edited grub.cfg manually

Comment: @Stephen - Can you please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/820502/edit) your question with the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` ?

Comment: done. need to add chars

Comment: Do you really have all those spaces in the first line of grub.cfg, or is that a posting artifact?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Doesn't really matter.

Comment: Just wondering about the "never manually edited" part.

Comment: except that i posted /etc/default/grub and you're talking about grub.cfg